# Problem installing cryptography on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, cryptography

I'm trying to install the cryptography package within a Docker container on a Raspberry Pi. It has worked before, but, for some reason, stopped working, when I had to rebuild my container.

When running

```
RUN pip install cryptography
```

This is the error message I get:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpnvp_3buk
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-h70clj5g/cryptography_5f6f98a08a774493a9829b0d6e8c5a6a
  Complete output (208 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/ocsp.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/x509
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_oid.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_cipheralgorithm.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_asymmetric.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/poly1305.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x25519.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backeFailed to build cryptography
nds/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed448.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed25519.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/aead.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/poly1305.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x448.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed448.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed25519.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/types.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x448.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/aead.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/ssh.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs7.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs12.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  running egg_info
  writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.github'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'mypy.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.d'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.playbooks'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.APACHE'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.BSD'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
  writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/cryptography/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/asn1.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/ocsp.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/x509.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.9/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_openssl.c'
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9
  running build_rust
      Updating crates.io index
  
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/ for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#rust
  
      Python: 3.9.7
      platform: Linux-5.10.63-v7+-armv7l-with-glibc2.28
      pip: n/a
      setuptools: 58.3.0
      setuptools_rust: 0.12.1
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 221, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 207, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 39, in <module>
      setup(
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 159, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 144, in run
      base_class.run(self)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools_rust/setuptools_ext.py", line 103, in run
      build_rust.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools_rust/command.py", line 52, in run
      self.run_for_extension(ext)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools_rust/build.py", line 92, in run_for_extension
      dylib_paths = self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-eus_qh_e/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools_rust/build.py", line 131, in build_extension
      metadata = json.loads(check_output(metadata_command))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cargo', 'metadata', '--manifest-path', 'src/rust/Cargo.toml', '--format-version', '1']' died with <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install cryptography' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

As suggested in the message I've already tried updating pip, but without any success. Not sure if it matters, but the base image is `python:3.9-slim-buster`

Edit:

Here is the Dockerfile up to the point where I try to install the cryptography package:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9-slim-buster

# define an alias for the specfic python version used in this file.
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION} as python

# Python build stage
FROM python as python-build-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=production

# Install apt packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev\
  libssl-dev \
  libffi-dev \
  libatlas-base-dev \
  cargo \
  rustc \
  gcc \
  libssl-dev \
  python3-dev \
  libjpeg62 \
  musl-dev \
  zlib1g-dev\
  libjpeg-dev \
  openssl

COPY ./requirements .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install cryptography
```

Edit 2:
The workaround from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118337/how-to-get-rid-of-cryptography-build-error) did solve my problem. It just doesn't seem to be very future proof to pin the cryptography version to sth. < 3.5

To be clear, this works:

```
ENV CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1
RUN pip install cryptography==3.4.6
```

Comment: The error message suggests four things; have you done all of them (especially checking the Rust toolchain)?  Can you edit the question to include your complete Dockerfile?

Comment: I've added the relevant part of the Dockerfile. I do too suppose it's based on the Rust toolchain. I'm unsure though, what I can do about it. Being a bit inexperienced with Docker & Linux/Raspbian.

Comment: same error on pyenv installed 3.8.1. and regular venv + pip install cryptography

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=326113) worked for me. TL;DR

```
sudo apt remove rustc
sudo curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue with Debian and cargo (the rust package installer) and nothing related to Python. Here is a reduced Dockerfile that demonstrates the problem (when run in an armhf container):

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y ca-certificates cargo rustc 
RUN USER=root cargo new --lib t
# works
RUN cargo metadata --manifest-path t/Cargo.toml
RUN echo 'libc = "*"' >> t/Cargo.toml
# segfaults
RUN cargo metadata --manifest-path t/Cargo.toml
```

This should be reported to [debbugs](https://debbugs.gnu.org), but I honestly can't unravel the correct reporting chain so good luck to whoever attempts it.

Update: this occurs on x86_64 as well so it likely affects all architectures.

Comment: It was kind of reported [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=998232), but I didn't try the suggested workaround since installing rust from source did the trick.