# Installing localstack on raspberry pi throws this error when called: AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, localstack

Trying to install localstack on a raspberry pi 3B using raspberrypi os with these specs:

Python: 3.9.2
platform: Linux-5.15.76-v7+-armv7l-with-glibc2.31
pip: n/a
setuptools: 65.5.1
setuptools_rust: 1.5.2
rustc: 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)

This problem seems to be fairly well documented but each solution and work around fails for me.

When I run the following commands as [detailed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743936/problem-installing-cryptography-on-raspberry-pi):

```
export CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1
pip install localstack
```

I get the same PEP 517 error when attempting to build the cryptography wheel.

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling rust as [detailed here](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/error-failed-building-wheel-for-cryptography/352020/12) and I'm still getting the PEP 517 error.

Cryptography appears to be installed when I do `pip install cryptography`. Is there a way to stop the local stack install from building the wheel using rust?

Edit: I realized that the problem was do to installing the 32-bit architecture I reimaged the using the 64-bit build [downloaded here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2022-09-26/). I reinstalled localstack using:

```
pip install local stack
```

It installed I rebooted then when I tried:

```
localstack --help
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/ci/github-actions/#installations-fails-with-attributeerror-module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509_v_flag_cb_issuer_check

> The issue is caused by a conflict of the pre-installed version of pyOpenSSL with newer versions of cryptography. Please manually upgrade by running `pip install --upgrade pyopenssl` before installing localstack to solve this issue.

On Ubuntu 20.04, I had an older python3-openssl version installed.
Uninstalling that would mean removing some system packages like gajim that I wanted to keep.
So I forced installation in my user account:

```
$ pip3 install pyopenssl --upgrade --force
```

When not using `--force`, pip would tell me that pyopenssl was already installed.