# Docker-compose not working on a different machine - Rust compiler

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to run a `docker compose` on a repo that I built in a W10 machine on a Mac machine. In both I am using a Conda env with python=3.7. I also did not install the requirements in the Mac machine, it is an empty Conda env with the base packages, as for my understanding, I do not need to in order to run the docker compose.

I also need these packages, where the error may come:

```
pip install transformers==4.12.4 sentencepiece
```

The repo only contains one microservice, whose Dockerfile copies and installs the requirements in the repository.

[image]

The problem comes when installing the requirements inside the Docker image. It is related to the Rust compiler, which I have not been able to install or solve.

Error log: https://pastebin.com/2hqZyL5Q

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install gcc -y \
    && apt-get clean

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt \
    && rm -rf /root/.cache/pip

COPY . /app/
```

requirements.txt

```
anyio==3.6.1
asgiref==3.5.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
autopep8==1.6.0
certifi==2022.5.18.1
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.4
Deprecated==1.2.13
fastapi==0.78.0
filelock==3.7.1
h11==0.13.0
huggingface-hub==0.7.0
idna==3.3
important==0.1.4
importlib-metadata==4.11.4
joblib==1.1.0
numpy==1.21.6
packaging==21.3
pycodestyle==2.8.0
pydantic==1.9.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
PyYAML==6.0
redis==4.3.3
regex==2022.6.2
requests==2.28.0
sacremoses==0.0.53
sentencepiece==0.1.96
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.2.0
starlette==0.19.1
tokenizers==0.10.3
toml==0.10.2
torch==1.11.0
tqdm==4.64.0
transformers==4.12.4
typing_extensions==4.2.0
urllib3==1.26.9
uvicorn==0.17.6
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.14.1
zipp==3.8.0
```

Comment: Install Rust within Docker image and use it `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.  Or even better, use multistage build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118337/how-to-get-rid-of-cryptography-build-error